# Ubuntu crashes due to read-heavy operations/high SSD temperatures

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, temperature

For a few days, I've noticed that my Ubuntu-based machine has started to freeze while performing read-intensive operations. The freezing, however, does not occur during write-intensive operations. Every time the device freezes, I manually plug off the power chord and shut the machine down forcefully; else, the laptop will stay frozen.

I monitored what happens to my SSD when I perform read-intensive operations using `hardinfo` and found out that my SSD sometimes goes over 70 degrees Celcius. The computer becomes unreliable at any SSD temperature above 60 degrees Celcius, and I've had crashes occur at temperatures as low as 62 degrees Celcius. I have tried the following solutions to solve this issue:

- `sudo fsck -y /dev/nvme0n1p3` to fix any file-system errors on partition three of my SSD (which is where all the data resides), but that didn't solve anything.
- I've also tried opening up my laptop chassis and cleaning any dust preventing airflow to the machine. That didn't seem to work as well.

I have seen SSDs reach 80+ degrees Celcius, which, although harmful to the longevity of the SSD, doesn't result in a crash. I think that when my system freezes, the SSD puts itself into read-only mode because all icons cease to show up a few seconds before the entire machine freezes.

This is the output of `sudo smartctl -i /dev/nvme0n1`:

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.17.15-76051715-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       SAMSUNG MZVLB1T0HBLR-000L2
Serial Number:                      S4DZNX0N709811
Firmware Version:                   3L1QEXF7
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Total NVM Capacity:                 1,024,209,543,168 [1.02 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      4
NVMe Version:                       1.3
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          1,024,209,543,168 [1.02 TB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            373,319,507,968 [373 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            002538 8701d0c0a0
Local Time is:                      Tue Jul 12 16:10:52 2022 IST
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: You could export kernel logs to an other system ( https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/netconsole.html#introduction ), hopefully getting useful logs related to the freeze.

Comment: Check your fan. Check to see if ventilation is blocked. Check the inside of your computer for dust. Dust coating of components keeps heat in.